# Are those errors related with bad syntax or updated package issues?

Tags: c#, botframework

Please, I am trying to figure out why still receiving these errors on my code below. I updated some packages before do some changes. I would like to know if new packages can cause errors or if it is just bad syntax. It is a simple bot with dialogs, using Bot Framework V4 and Visual Studio 15.8.8. The list of errors are:

- The modifiers private not valid for this item
- The modifier private not valid for this item
- Names NameStepAsync and NameConfirmStepAsync doesn't exist for the current context.
- A local or parameter name cancellationToken can not be declared.
- A package restore failed.
- A detected package downgrade.

All errors codes links to different examples. Other errors I could solve by myself. I will appreciate all feedback and can provide more info, but please help me.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;

namespace IcidBotOne
{

    public class EchoWithCounterBot : IBot
    {

        private DialogSet _dialogs;
        private readonly EchoBotAccessors _accessors;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;


        public EchoWithCounterBot(EchoBotAccessors accessors)


        {
            // Set the _accessors
            _accessors = accessors ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));
            // The DialogSet needs a DialogState accessor, it will call it when it has a turn context.
            _dialogs = new DialogSet(accessors.ConversationDialogState);
            // This array defines how the Waterfall will execute.
            var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                NameStepAsync,
                NameConfirmStepAsync,
            };
            // Add named dialogs to the DialogSet. These names are saved in the dialog state.
            _dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("details", waterfallSteps));
            _dialogs.Add(new TextPrompt("name"));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Every conversation turn for our Echo Bot will call this method.
        /// There are no dialogs used, since it's "single turn" processing, meaning a single
        /// request and response.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="turnContext">A <see cref="ITurnContext"/> containing all the data needed
        /// for processing this conversation turn. </param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">(Optional) A <see cref="CancellationToken"/> that can be used by other objects
        /// or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> that represents the work queued to execute.</returns>
        /// <seealso cref="BotStateSet"/>
        /// <seealso cref="ConversationState"/>
        /// <seealso cref="IMiddleware"/>
        public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            // Handle Message activity type, which is the main activity type for shown within a conversational interface
            // Message activities may contain text, speech, interactive cards, and binary or unknown attachments.
            // see https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types
            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                // Get the conversation state from the turn context.
                var state = await _accessors.CounterState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new CounterState());

                // Bump the turn count for this conversation.
                state.TurnCount++;
                if (!state.SaidHello)
                {
                    // MARCUS: Handlle the Greeting
                    string strMessage = $"Hello World! {System.Environment.NewLine}";
                    strMessage += "Talk to me and I will repeat it back!";
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(strMessage);

                    // MARCUS: Set SaidHello
                    state.SaidHello = true;
                }

                // Run the DialogSet - let the framework identify the current state of the dialog from
                // the dialog stack and figure out what (if any) is the active dialog.
                var dialogContext = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
                // If the DialogTurnStatus is Empty we should start a new dialog.
                if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
                {
                    await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync("details", null, cancellationToken);
                }

                // Set the property using the accessor. OK
                await _accessors.CounterState.SetAsync(turnContext, state);

                // Save the new turn count into the conversation state. OK
                await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
            }

            private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> NameStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
            // Running a prompt here means the next Waterfall
            // will be run when the user response is received.
                    return await stepContext.PromptAsync("name", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("What is your name?") }, cancellationToken);
            }

            private async Task<DialogTurnResult> NameConfirmStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                    // We can send messages to the user at any point in the WaterfallStep.
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello {stepContext.Result}!"), cancellationToken);
                    // WaterfallStep always finishes with the end of the Waterfall or with another dialog,
                    // here it is the end.
                    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're defining NameStepAsync and NameConfirmStepAsync inside of OnTurnAsync. Go ahead and move their definitions outside of OnTurnAsync onto the class level and let us know if you're still getting problems with the packages.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. No errors anymore and packages are ok!

Comment: Okay, I've made my comment an answer in case you want to accept it

Comment: Kyle, sorry, I'm rather new at SO and I didn't know about that. I should have checked the rules first :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining NameStepAsync and NameConfirmStepAsync inside of OnTurnAsync. Go ahead and move their definitions outside of OnTurnAsync onto the class level.